# Question on evaluation functional for polynomials.

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

For $P_3$ as set of polynomials of degree less than or equal to 3 with basis 1,(1-x),$(1,x)^2$,$(1-x)^3$. What would be the matrix representation of linear functional (Evaluation function) $ev_3: P_3 -> R$. If $(f_1,f_2,f_3,f_4)$ be the dual basis of $P_3$. For the polynomial $p=x^3+5x^2+3x+4$ belonging to $P_3$. How do I get $f_3(p)$.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $\;p(1-x)=(1-x)^3+5(1-x)^2+3(1-x)+4 = -x^3+8 x^2-16 x+13$

$$p(x) = p\big((1- (1-x)\big)=-(1-x)^3+8(1-x)^2-16(1-x)+13$$

Answer (score 0):

Find $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb R$ such that

$p(x)=a+b(1-x)+c(1-x)^2+d(1-x)^3$.

Then $f_3(p)=c$